# File not found in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, file-not-found

I am wondering why Xcode reports that `Yoga.h` is not found.

I tried:

- Deleting the file, closing Xcode, opening Xcode, and adding the file again.
- Changing the file location from *"Relative to group"* to *"Relative to project"*.

I think it is because the file is broken – when I was typing the file name, the full name did not automatically show up even though I already imported into the project.

[image]

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447860/xcode-file-not-found