# UnityAppController.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

When I build my unity IOS app on Xcode through Unity 2019.2.9f1. **UnityAppController.h file not found** error occurred.

On Xcode, I can see there's UnityAppController.h file. However, when clicking the file, the script does not show up.

These sites below are what I referred. But Xcode still shows the same error. If there's anyone who's familiar with how to handle this issue, would you give some advice? Combatting with this error for days is exhausting.

[Xcode file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447860/xcode-file-not-found)

['UnityAppController.h' file not found #53](https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5/issues/53)

[/UnityAppController.h](https://github.com/naveensundarg/catabotrescue-unity/blob/master/ios/Classes/UnityAppController.h)

[Unity3D 4.2 building for iOS results in "AppController.h file not found" error](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity3d-4-2-building-for-ios-results-in-appcontroller-h-file-not-found-error.197934/)

[Importing unity xcode projet into existing xcode app projet](https://answers.unity.com/questions/673645/importing-unity-xcode-projet-into-existing-xcode-a.html)

[UnityのiOSでAppDelegateに処理を追加する](https://starzero.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/02/24/182646)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just try to import unity facebook sdk package in your project:

step1: Download facebook unity sdk from [Unity Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/)

step2: import package in unity goto Assets/Import Package/Custom Package then locate your downloaded sdk.

step3: Now just build and run your project.